# How could we do temporal filtering for video processing?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I am reading the slides for temporal filtering in  [Computer vision](http://6.869.csail.mit.edu/fa16/lecture/lecture3linearfilters.pdf) (page 108) class and i am wondering how can we do temporal filtering for videos?

For example they say our data is a vide which is in XYT, whre X,Y are spatial domain and T is time.
**"How could we create a filter that keeps sharp objects that move at some velocity (vx, vy)while blurring the rest?"**
and they kinda drive the formula for that, but im confused how to apply it?
How can  we do filtering in Fourie Domain , how should we apply that in general? can someone please help me how should i code it?

Comment: "Do we apply it in Fourie Domain or some other domain..?" Depends all on the details. You can filter in the Fourier Domain, but you can also filter in the real domain. The formula they derived and the derivation should tell you all about it. "how should i code it?" Depends again on the details. Just assume that video data is represented as 3D data arrays with dimensions XYT. I think this question is not really a good one. It's unclear to me what exactly you need help with. Maybe you can become more specific? For example: Concentrate on one filter, present the formula for it and ask on that.

Comment: @Trilarion Sorry if my question is not clear or is stupid. I am newbie in video processing and just try to learn it better.
when I say "Do we apply it in Fourie Domain or some other domain," I meant how we can do it in Fourie domain, because for 2D example convolution become multiply in Fourie, and make it so easy. I assume for 3D it is the same, but it does not make sense to me how it works in general in Fourie Domain

Comment: You really want to ask how to apply a convolution using the Fourier transform in Matlab?

Comment: i know how to do it in 1D and 2D, but not sure how to do it in 3D :/

Answer (score 1):

In that example, they're talking about a specific known speed. For example, if you know that a car is moving left at 2 pixels per frame. It's possible to make a video that blurs everything except that car.

Here's the idea: start at frame 0 of the video. At each pixel, look one frame in the future, and 2 pixels left. You will be looking at the same part of the moving car. Now, imagine you take the average color value between your current pixel & the future pixel (the one that is 2 pixels left, and 1 frame in the future). If your pixel is on the moving car, both pixels will be the exact same color, so taking the average has no effect. On the other hand, if it's NOT on the moving car, they'll be different colors, and so take the average will have the effect of blurring between them.

Thus, the pixels of the car will be unchanged, but the rest of the video will get a blur. Repeat for each frame. You can also include more frames in your filter; e.g. you could look 2 frames in the future and 4 pixels left, or 1 frame in the past and 2 pixels right.

Note: this was a teaching example; I don't think there are many real computer vision applications for this (at least, not as a standalone technique), because it's so fragile. If the car speeds up or slows down slightly, it gets blurred.

Comment: thank you for your response.
is there a way to know (instead of 2 pixels) how many pixel we should look left/right automatically?

Comment: You would need to determine that separately, via a different algorithm. For example, you could use the optic flow algorithm to detect regions of pixels that move together. Or use SURF keypoints to track an object. (That's why I said this technique doesn't have many applications on its own: usually you don't know the speed of objects, so it's not very useful).